# Maximising the area of a triangle when the 3 sides are at most 2, 3, 4

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

This is question 5 from the 2012 BMO1, please can someone provide a full solution? There is an online video solution but is incomplete as it assumes that the area of a triangle is maximised when two side lengths are maximised without justification. Thank you.

Comment: This site isn't a mill for churning out solutions to contest problems. You can find the solution through a quick Google search (it took me no more than two minutes).

Comment: How about maximizing Heron’s formula for the area of a triangle given its three sides and semi-perimeter?

Comment: @Théophile, apologies, but the solution online is incomplete, it assumes that two side lengths have to be maximised to maximise the area of a triangle, but does not justify this claim.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius, I have tried and it becomes a problem of maximising $2a^2b^2+2a^2c^2+2b^2c^2-a^4-b^4-c^4$ (where $a, b, c$ are the side lengths of the triangle). I am unsure how to continue.

Comment: @3684 Thank you for adding context. If you're referring to the proof provided at [this BMO site](https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/solutions/bmo1-2013/), then the justification is given from 0:40 to 1:00.

Comment: @Théophile, I don't believe the justification is complete, for an obtuse triangle, increasing either one of its two longest lengths will actually decrease it's area,  and obtuse triangles are possible in the given parameters.

Comment: @3684 A triangle's area is determined by its base and height. If the base is fixed and the other two sides can be made longer, then we can increase the area by pulling the vertex away from the base so as to increase the height. This is true whether or not the triangle is obtuse.

Comment: @Théophile, please draw a diagram and see for yourself.

Comment: @3684 Do you agree that increasing the height of a triangle increases its area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one of the triangle sides has to be maximized, equal to 2, 3 or 4. If all sides are shorter, it is always possible to scale up the triangle until one side reaches the maximum value. And that triangle certainly has a bigger area. So we have three cases to check: the maximized side can be 2, 3 or 4.

Case AB=2: Draw circles with radii 3 and 4 with points A and B as centers. The third vertex of the triangle has to be somewhere in the common area of these two circles. The most distant point from AB is the optimal solution (because it gives the maximum triangle height). And that's point C' (giving triangle ABC' with sides 2, 3, $\sqrt{13}$), not point C (giving triangle ABC with sides 2, 3 and 4).

[image]

Case AB=3: Same as above, just a slightly different picture. Draw circles with radii 2 and 4. Optimal triangle ABC' is actually the same as in the previous case with sides 2, 3, $\sqrt{13}$.

[image]

Case AB=4: In this case, the most distant point is actually the intersection point of circles with radii 2 and 3 and centers A,B. The otimal triangle is the triangle ABC with sides 2, 3 and 4. But in the first case we already saw that that solution is inferior to triangle with sides $2, 3, \sqrt{13}$

[image]

So the soluton to this problem is $2,3,\sqrt{13}$